# Is it safe to rely on MySQL Cascade for delete

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb

I'm using the PHP Laravel Framework, but it's a general PHP question. Is it safe to use the MySQL foreign key relation on delete cascade to delete related rows ? Or is it a best practice to do it in PHP ? I find the cascade system realy nice but don't know if it's safe to use it ? Any best practices ?

For example when you have a user that have created posts and that user is deleted, do you delete his posts with PHP then delete the user, or just use cascade ?

Thanks for your feedbacks.

Comment: I would imagine you could rely on the cascading effect.  It is like asking if you can rely on using the `DELETE` syntax in SQL.  I think the only thing you would need to worry about is the effects of a cascading delete.  You may suddenly find rows deleted from your DB that were unexpected.  E.g.: deleting products from a product table suddenly deletes the items from the invoiced orders table as well.

Comment: You definitely should rely on foreign keys instead of doing the same thing by yourself in the application.

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but if decide to switch to another storage engine which is different from MySQL and which might not support this feature (db like Mongo, Maria) you will have to rewrite a lot of storage iterations. So if you care about possibility to switch to another db storage, **then NO, Implement it on the server-side language**, otherwise you can keep using CASCADES. And also, learn about **Data Mapper** pattern, it should be used here definitely.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can rely on CASCADE deletes.  If you define a relationship with ON DELETE CASCADE, the foriegn row will definitely be deleted.  Using ON DELETE CASCADE is definitely reccommended (assuming you want to delete the related rows), and it is likely more reliable than implementing the delete cascade in your application.

In the example you gave, the rows containing the users posts were related to the user using a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE.  In this case, you would just delete the user.  MySQL will follow all of the relationships and delete all related rows.  This wil prevent orphaned data.  Doing it via the application is much more "risky" in terms of the potential for orphaning data.

Keep in mind, however, if there are other relationships to the same data (e.g. there are reply posts relating to the user's post who is going to be deleted), the delete can be blocked, since the reference in the reply row would be dangling.  Of course, this is all dependent on your database design and how you set up your foreign keys.